# How to rewrite a URL in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have url: `domain.com/articles/index.php?article_id=1&lang_id=1`
in sql database I have title and permalinks (unique permalinks).

The article title is: article title
The permalink: article-title-permalink

Is there any way to rewrite:

this link: `domain.com/articles/index.php?article_id=1&lang_id=1`
to this: `domain.com/article-title-permalink`
or to this: `domain.com/article-title`

I am novice. I have searched everywhere but couldn't get result. I even bought several courses, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up concepts and words.

My guess is that you want somebody to point his browser to `domain.com/article-title-permalink` and your application, somehow (we'll get there), to execute the code in `domain.com/articles/index.php?article_id=1&lang_id=1`

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

There is no direct way to do that, but what you can do is to replace your index.php file to, instead of expecting an `article_id` parameter, expect the `article_permalink` parameter, so this way you can rewrite the URL, using the `.htacces` file, as you tagged your question with ti, to do that.

Would that help? 
There is more ways to solve this, but i guess it depends on the context of what you want/need.

Comment: You are right. can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: and one more question:
I use codeigniter framework.
Url for the article is domain.com/articles/view/about-us

I want somebody to point his browser to : domain.com/about-us and my application somehow to execute the code: domain.com/about-us

Thank you very much

Comment: Check the duplicated link where you can find an entire explanation on how to use .htaccess Rewrite commands.